# Can't call method "model" on an undefined value at

Tags: perl, catalyst, dbix-class, moosex-types

I have been building catalyst apps of a number of years now.  This is the first time I am getting an error trying to open a view.  When I call the view (there is only one view), I get the following error:

**Can't call method "model" on an undefined value at....**

The following snippet of code is used in Root.pm,.  This is what is generating the error on the browser.  Again, this is not the first time I am using this catalyst method to call a model.

`my $model = $c->model( 'mypackage' );`
`my $result = $model->get_my_results();`

The alternative is to use:
`use mypackage;`
`my $model = 'mypackage';`
`my $results = $model->get_my_results();`

Has any one ever encounter this before?  If yes, can you tell me how you resolved it.

Thanks

***EDITED***
Please note, as indicated in the original post, this is a Perl Catalyst app. The $c is a Catalyst object. In the Root.pm file, $c is received as follows:

`sub myform :Local {`
  `my ($self, $c) = @_;`
  `my $model = $c->model( 'mypackage' );`
  `my $results = $model->get_my_results();`
  `.`
  `.`
  `.`
`}`

Comment: What model are you using? Please also paste the whole code so we can see where $c comes from.

Answer (score 1):

Typo?  Did you mean `$c->model` in your first line?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Yes, I understand your critique.  But I'm still newbie enough to be unable to comment on other people's posts.

Comment: @Secator: no, I suspect this is the answer, even if phrased as a question.

Comment: @KevinHinshaw, there is a `add a comment` link in grey at the end of any question or answer. If there are already comments on that question/answer, the link is below the last comment.

Comment: @MarcelGosselin: you need 50 reputation before you can leave comments

Comment: Yes, it was a typo, since I typed it, rather than cutting and pasting. It should have been $c->model not $c->mode.  I corrected it in the original post, along with additional information.  However, there is no typo in the original application.

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured out the path of my evil ways.  I inadvertently forgot to pass $c in the calling method.  Therefore the $c in myform() had no value.  Hence, it could not find the Catalyst method called "model".

`sub myform :Local {`
   `my ($self, $c) = @_;`
   `my $model = $c->model( 'mypackage' );`
   `my $results = $model->get_my_results();`
   `.`
   `.`
   `.`
`}`

`sub someother_method :Local {`
   `my ($self, $c) = @_;`
   `.`
   `.`
   `.`
   `my $myform_info = $self->myform($c)`  **<---this was missing the $c**
   `.`
`}`